# save element nodechilds in the same type as element in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, clone, nodes

```
 var old_element=document.getElementById('dhtml_menu-1895');    
 var old_element_child=old_element.children;    
  console.log(old_element_child);
```

output a nodelist object

i would like to have old_element_child in the same type as old_element to be able to do

```
var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
var new_element_child=new_element.children;     
old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);  
old_element.replaceChild(old_element_child, new_element_child);
```

Answer (score 1):

The children property returns a nodelist of all the children of a given element (even if it's only one, which seems to be the case). What you want is an specific element, for that you could either use

```
 var old_element_child = old_element.children[n];
```

n being the index of the desired child inside the parent (0 based). So if it's the first child it would be

```
var old_element_child = old_element.children[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try copying your object in this way:**

The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```
var old_element=document.getElementById('dhtml_menu-1895'); 

var copy = Object.assign({}, old_element);
console.log(copy); // here is your object copyed
```